# Is there a more elegant solution to store and process different types using templates?

Tags: c++, performance, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to create some system for profiling and I need to track different data types (double, float int). I have a container that can hold some base type, and then perform actions on the concrete type by switching on the enum or something similar. I need to have a base type so the data can be copied/passed around if necessary.

I wanted to stay with a templated approach since there are only a handful of types and all of the initial data and types are known at compile time, but open to others. This makes it easier at call-sites where users can pass in the concrete types to the container to add to the storage. `container.Add(ConcreteType, value)`

I can't use the modern variations of variant/boost::any, and I'm using c++17.

Here is a minimal example that compiles

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdint.h>

enum DataType
{
    DOUBLE, FLOAT, INT
};

template <typename T>
struct WrappedType
{
    void Add(T value)
    {
        m_value += value;
    }

    T m_value{};
    //...
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeStorage
{
    WrappedType<T> m_wrapper;
    //...
};

struct BaseTypeInfo
{
    DataType m_type;
    uint32_t m_index;
    //...
};

struct DoubleType : public BaseTypeInfo
{
    using type = double;
};

struct FloatType : public BaseTypeInfo
{
    using type = float;
};

struct IntType : public BaseTypeInfo
{
    using type = int;
};

struct Data
{
    union
    {
        TypeStorage<double> m_double{};
        TypeStorage<float> m_float;
        TypeStorage<int> m_int;
    };

    const BaseTypeInfo* m_info; //contains DataType
};

template <int SIZE>
struct Container
{
    void Add(const DoubleType& type, double value)
    {
        Data& data = m_data[type.m_index];
        data.m_info = &type;
        data.m_double.m_wrapper.Add(value);
    }

    void Add(const FloatType &type, float value)
    {
        Data& data = m_data[type.m_index];
        data.m_info = &type;
        data.m_float.m_wrapper.Add(value);
    }

    void Add(const IntType& type, int value)
    {
        Data& data = m_data[type.m_index];
        data.m_info = &type;
        data.m_int.m_wrapper.Add(value);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void GetData(const Data& data, T&& callable)
    {
        switch (data.m_info->m_type)
        {
        case DOUBLE:
            callable(data.m_double.m_wrapper);
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            callable(data.m_float.m_wrapper);
            break;
        case INT:
            callable(data.m_int.m_wrapper);
            break;
        }
    }


    Data m_data[SIZE];
};

static BaseTypeInfo infos[32];
static uint32_t numInfos = 0;

const DoubleType& AddDoubleType(const char* name)
{
    uint32_t index = numInfos++;

    BaseTypeInfo& info = infos[index];
    info.m_type = DOUBLE;
    info.m_index = index;
    //..
    return static_cast<const DoubleType&>(info);
}
const FloatType& AddFloatType(const char* name)
{
    uint32_t index = numInfos++;

    BaseTypeInfo& info = infos[index];
    info.m_type = FLOAT;
    info.m_index = index;
    //..
    return static_cast<const FloatType&>(info);
}
const IntType& AddIntType(const char* name)
{
    uint32_t index = numInfos++;

    BaseTypeInfo& info = infos[index];
    info.m_type = INT;
    info.m_index = index;
    //..

    return static_cast<const IntType&>(info);
}

const DoubleType& doubleType = AddDoubleType("");
const FloatType& floatType = AddFloatType("");
const IntType& intType = AddIntType("");

struct PrintFunctor
{
    PrintFunctor(const Data* data) : m_data(data) {}

    template <typename T>
    void operator()(const WrappedType<T>& wrappedType)
    {
        Print(wrappedType.m_value);
    }


private:
    void Print(double value) { printf("DOUBLE: %f\n", value); }
    void Print(float value) { printf("FLOAT: %f\n", value); }
    void Print(int value) { printf("INT: %d\n", value); }

    const Data* m_data;
};

int main()
{
    static constexpr uint32_t CONTAINER_SIZE = 32;
    Container<CONTAINER_SIZE> container;

    container.Add(doubleType, 5.0);
    container.Add(floatType, 10.0f);
    container.Add(intType, 15);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        Data& data = container.m_data[i];

        //could switch on type here, but want to hide it away as much as possible as there are a few places iterating the list

        //opt 1 lambda, but template arg lambdas are not in c++17, would have to pass a dummy argument to use decltype, to get the actual type in the wrapper?
        auto lambda = [](auto& wrapped_type) //type should be WrappedType<T>, need to obtain T to then pass to some print function?
        {
            //
        };
        container.GetData(data, lambda);

        //opt 2 functor, user code still needs to do some switching on type, can get messy
        PrintFunctor func(&data);
        container.GetData(data, func);
    }
}
```

There are some comments in the main function, haven't managed to get the lambda working in c++17, and the functors are getting messy.

Is there a nicer way to achieve this with my limitations?

Comment: This doesn't compile? `error: use of deleted function ‘Container<32>::Container()`

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. The title of the question should state what the code is doing rather than your concerns about the code. On code review we want to see actual working code from a project you have written, not a minimized subset of the code. Please read [A guide to code review for stack overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Parts of this code appear to have been removed (`//..`), but for review we need _complete_ code.  Please [edit] to reinstate the missing parts when you fix the title.  Also, I don't see any meta-programming, so reconsider your tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Implement your own variant type

> I can't use the modern variations of variant/boost::any, and I'm using c++17.

Weird, since C++17 includes `std::variant`, but perhaps you are on  some restricted system that doesn't have the full C++17 library support. Reinderien showed one possible approach that uses inheritance, but you said:

> Ideally looking for an approach without using dynamic dispatch

Then [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) really does look like the best solution for you, so if you cannot use the STL's implementation, I suggest you implement your own (as well as a corresponding [`std::visit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)). Because that way, you can just write:

```
using Data = my_variant<double, float, int>;

int main() {
    std::array<Data, 3> container = {5.0, 10.0f, 15};

    for (auto &d: container) {
        my_visit([](auto& d) {
            std::cout << typeid(d).name() << ": " << d << '\n';
        }, d);
    }
}
```

There are plenty of examples on the Internet that describe how to create your own variant type.

Comment: Thanks this is likely what I need to look into, even if it’s a more stripped down version of variant.

Answer (score 4):

"Yikes".

Don't use `cstdio` in C++.

Having a type `enum` mirror the C++ type system is an anti-pattern, and is avoidable here with proper use of templates.

This is way more complex than it needs to be. Delete basically everything, and reduce down to two classes: a non-template abstract parent, and a `template` child.

`union` is not called-for here.

Don't make your own container. Use a built-in; in this case `std::array`.

### Suggested

The following outputs the same as your program:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


namespace {

class AbstractData {
public:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const AbstractData &d) {
        return d.write(out);
    }

    virtual const char *name() const = 0;

protected:
    virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &out) const = 0;
};



template <typename T>
class Data: public AbstractData {
public:
    constexpr Data(T value): value(value) { }

    constexpr const char *name() const;
    
private:
    constexpr std::ostream &write(std::ostream &out) const {
        return out << value;
    }
    
    T value;
};


template<> constexpr const char *Data<double>::name() const { return "DOUBLE"; }
template<> constexpr const char *Data<float>::name() const { return "FLOAT"; }
template<> constexpr const char *Data<int>::name() const { return "INT"; }

}

int main() {
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<AbstractData>, 3> container = {
        std::unique_ptr<AbstractData>(new Data<double>(5.0)),
        std::unique_ptr<AbstractData>(new Data<float>(10.0f)),
        std::unique_ptr<AbstractData>(new Data<int>(15))
    };

    for (std::unique_ptr<AbstractData> &d: container)
        std::cout << d->name() << ": " << *d << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
DOUBLE: 5
FLOAT: 10
INT: 15
```

Comment: Ideally looking for an approach without using dynamic dispatch given there is only three types I need to cover. I cannot use cout, and *Container* in this example is not an attempt to roll my own container, it’s just a fixed array and a way to add the types into it.

Comment: Dynamic dispatch can be justified if there are only _two_ types to cover; so you'll need more justification than that. Why can't you use `cout`? And... "a fixed array with a way to add the types into it" is a container. You literally named it `Container`.

Comment: I’m on a limited system that favours performance and has their own logging, and requires more of a printf approach, hence the use of cstdio as an example. The underlying type of *Container* can be a std array no problem.. this was a way to group some functions together

Comment: Have you profiled a dynamic dispatch approach compared to yours?